# Python 3.5 on multiple users

Tags: python, windows-10

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this, but shall ask it regardless.

My situation is that I am setting up new machines at school, and am having trouble with a few programs. Specifically, python 3.5. I've installed the app on the local user account without issue. I also have python 2.7 if that is any consolation. Anyways, the students at the school sign into the machines from our domain. This is where I am experiencing an issue. When I sign in through the domain, the app is not there or accessible. I've created a desktop shortcut for the application, so that when the users login they can just access it from there (because it was not showing up in the start menu), and it comes up with an error saying it is unable to find the application.

Would anyone have any insight on how to remedy this problem?

Thank you! -Tristen

Comment: Does python 3.6.3 give the same trouble ?

Comment: I can test it out. I'm just confused concerning why 2.7 would present no issue, but 3.5 would.